# What is "*;1" in TADOStoredProc.ProcedureName value in Delphi?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, ado

You may specify TADOStoredProc.ProcedureName in Delphi with the following value:

```
MSSQLProcedureName;1
```

But what does meen ";1" in this value?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an optional value that can be used to specify multiple definitions for the same stored procedure name... I think that the original intention was to allow versioning, but I've never seen it used that way in the wild.

When you don't specify the number in the `create procedure` statement, it defaults to `1`.  Some of the various data access layers that call SQL Server will explicitly add the `;1` when executing the stored procedure.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> `;*number*`
>
> Is an optional integer used to group procedures of the same name so
>   they can be dropped together with a single DROP PROCEDURE statement.
>   For example, the procedures used with an application called orders may
>   be named orderproc;1, orderproc;2, and so on. The statement DROP
>   PROCEDURE orderproc drops the entire group. If the name contains
>   delimited identifiers, the number should not be included as part of
>   the identifier; use the appropriate delimiter around procedure_name
>   only.